# Conformal laplacian on asymptotically flat manifolds with boundary

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry

Let $g$ be an asymptotically flat metric on $M = \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus B_1$ where $B_1$ is the unit ball.

Suppose $X$ is a smooth vector field on $M$ that is decaying exponentially and satisfies
$$\Delta_{g,conf} X - fX= 0$$
where $f$ is some smooth function and $\Delta_{g,conf}$ is the conformal laplacian defined as the divergence of the traceless part of ${L}_X g$.

Does there exist a function $f$ such that $X=0$ is the only possible solution to the above? You can assume $f$ is a function of points in $M$ and/or of $X$.

If we assume in addition that $X$ vanishes on $\partial M$, then a simple integration by parts argument shows that if $f\geq0$, then $X$ must be a conformal Killing field that decays and so must be $0$.

But does it hold without the assumption that $X$ vanishes on $\partial M$? If not, what if we know that $X$ on $\partial M$ lies on a fixed finite dimensional space? (such as the space of conformal killing fields on $\partial M$.)

Comment: What are the conditions you intend to put on $f$? If $f$ is a non-zero constant, you would expect non-trivial solutions with exponentially fast decay.

Comment: $f$ can be any smooth function of $p$ and/or $X$ where $p \in M$. So this could be a nonlinear PDE. Constant $f$ doesn't work because, as you said, there can be nontrivial solutions.

Comment: Do you impose a sign constraint on $f$?

Comment: no, no constraint on $f$. I need any smooth $f$ such that the operator $\Delta_{g,conf} - f$ is injective.